# how to change the default load ajax loader gif in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have already seen the docs for jquery mobile but couldn't understand how to integrate it on my mobile website. The docs are here at

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-pre/docs/pages/loader.html
```

Actually the gif image doesn't animate on 2.x android devices so I am thinking about making a text only kind of pre loading widget.

I tried changing it via css like this

```
.ui-icon-loading {
            background: url(themes/images/custom-ajax-loader.gif);
        }
```

but the new imag doesn't scale properly and the old background is still visible.

I am a complete noob with javascript.can someone plz help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mentioning the jQM 1.2 Alpha Docs so my answer is based in this jQM version.

Below you can find 2 options to change the default loader image.

**Solution 1**

As stated in the jQM 1.2 Alpha Docs:

> When jQuery Mobile starts, it triggers a mobileinit event on the document object. To override default settings, bind to mobileinit. Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. Link to your JavaScript files in the following order:
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
> ```

To configure the loading dialog globally the following settings can be defined on its prototype during the mobileinit event:

```
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```

Below you can find a working example in which you can fully customize the loader in the **html prototype option**.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textonly = false;
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all'><img src='../images/my-custom-image.png' /><h2>loading</h2></span>";
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {          
                $.mobile.loading('show');
            });
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <button class="show-page-loading-msg">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2**

Override the default CSS styles used to depict the page loader.

**EDITED**

For [jQM 1.1.1 version](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html) there are the following configurable options:

> - loadingMessage string, default: "loading" 
>     Set the text that appears when a page is loading. If set to false, the message will not appear at all.
> - loadingMessageTextVisible boolean, default: false 
>     Whether the text should be visible when a loading message is shown. The text is always visible for loading errors.
> - loadingMessageTheme string, default: "a" 
>     The theme that the loading message box uses when text is visible.

Code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
               $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme = 'e';
               $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
                $.mobile.loadingMessage = "test";
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {          
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            });
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                <button class="show-page-loading-msg">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Furthermore you could try to override the default CSS used to style the jQM loader. More specifically you could modify or override the styles in the section **loading screen** and the style in the section **loading icon** which are used to depict the page loader.

You will find [here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css) the CSS used in jQM 1.1.1.

```
/* loading icon */
.ui-icon-loading {
    background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);
    background-size: 46px 46px;
}

/* loading screen */
.ui-loading .ui-loader { display: block; }
.ui-loader { display: none; z-index: 9999999; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; border:0; }
.ui-loader-default { background: none; opacity: .18; width: 46px; height: 46px; margin-left: -23px; margin-top: -23px; }
.ui-loader-verbose { width: 200px; opacity: .88; box-shadow: 0 1px 1px -1px #fff; height: auto; margin-left: -110px; margin-top: -43px; padding: 10px; }
.ui-loader-default h1 { font-size: 0; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.ui-loader-verbose h1 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0; text-align: center; }
.ui-loader .ui-icon { background-color: #000; display: block; margin: 0; width: 44px; height: 44px; padding: 1px; -webkit-border-radius: 36px; -moz-border-radius: 36px; border-radius: 36px; }
.ui-loader-verbose .ui-icon { margin: 0 auto 10px; opacity: .75; }
.ui-loader-textonly { padding: 15px; margin-left: -115px; }
.ui-loader-textonly .ui-icon { display: none; }
.ui-loader-fakefix { position: absolute; }
```

Comment: by the way i am using the latest stable version 1.1.1...is it different for this version?

Comment: Yes, it is different. I thought you were using jQM 1.2 because the posted link referred to jQM 1.2.

Comment: actually the docs pointed to the same thing so i pasted that  ...I didn't know about that..thanks for pointing that out..so what should i use for 1.1.1?

Comment: I've added possible solutions for jQM 1.1.1. I hope this helps :)